# Not being able to write&read data from the 24C04N EEPROM using I2C

Tags: arduino, i2c, eeprom, atmega328p, arduino-uno

##### I have connected the **24C04N** EEPROM to the **ATmega328p** like this -

[image]
*Image source - Google*

##### The only difference is I connected the ATmega328p on a breadboard using FTDI like this -

[image]
*Image source - This is my actual circuit*

1. Pull-up resistors on the I2C bus is - 10 kΩ.
2. A0, A1, A2 connected to ground.
3. Write protect pin connected to ground.

The ATmega328p on breadboard is working fine-tested. And all the connection to the EEPROM is also good-I checked it using a multi-meter.

1. Voltage to ATmega328p - 5 V.
2. External crystal - 16 MHz.

##### And here is the exact EEPROM I have/bought -

[enter link description here](https://robu.in/product/at24c04n-4k-bit-serial-i2c-bus-eeprom-ic-dip-8-package/)

##### And here is my code from Arduino IDE -

**TWI_Master**

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

void TWI_init();
uint8_t TWI_start(unsigned char);
uint8_t TWI_repeated_start(unsigned char);
uint8_t TWI_write(unsigned char);
unsigned char TWI_read_ack();
unsigned char TWI_read_nack();
void TWI_stop();

int main()
{
  //This ports are used for, We can say to Debug
  DDRB |= (1<<DDB5) | (1<<DDB4) | (1<<DDB3) | (1<<DDB2) | (1<<DDB1) | (1<<DDB0);
  DDRD |= (1<<DDD5) | (1<<DDD6) | (1<<DDD7);
  uint8_t st;
  unsigned char dat;
  
  TWI_init();
  st = TWI_start(0xA0); //SLA + W
  //If NACK received then PB5 HIGH
  if(st==2){PORTB|=(1<<PORTB5);}else{PORTB&=~(1<<PORTB5);} // ---I get-->HIGH---
  st = TWI_write(0x22);
  //If NACK received then PB4 HIGH
  if(st==1){PORTB|=(1<<PORTB4);}else{PORTB&=~(1<<PORTB4);} // ---I get-->HIGH---
  st = TWI_write(0x97);
  //If NACK received then PB3 HIGH
  if(st==1){PORTB|=(1<<PORTB3);}else{PORTB&=~(1<<PORTB3);} // ---I get-->HIGH---
  TWI_stop();
  _delay_ms(500);
  
  st = TWI_start(0xA0);
  //If NACK received then PD5 HIGH
  if(st==2){PORTD|=(1<<PORTD5);}else{PORTD&=~(1<<PORTD5);} // ---I get-->HIGH---
  st = TWI_write(0x22);
  //If NACK received then PD6 HIGH
  if(st==1){PORTD|=(1<<PORTD6);}else{PORTB&=~(1<<PORTD6);} // ---I get-->HIGH---
  st = TWI_repeated_start(0xA1); //SLA + R
  //If NACK received then PD7 HIGH
  if(st==2){PORTD|=(1<<PORTD7);}else{PORTD&=~(1<<PORTD7);} // ---I get-->HIGH---
  dat = TWI_read_nack(); 
  TWI_stop();
  _delay_ms(500);
  //If dat=0x97 then PB0 HIGH
  if(dat==0x97){PORTB|=(1<<PORTB0);}else{PORTB&=~(1<<PORTB0);}  // ---I get-->LOW---
  
  while(1)
  {
    //loop
  }
  return 0;
}

void TWI_init()
{
  //Prescalar set to 1. 
  //---I also tried other prescaling options but didn't work---
  TWSR &= ~(1<<TWPS0);
  TWSR &= ~(1<<TWPS1);
  //---I also tried other bitrates but didn't work---
  TWBR = 72; //((16000000/100000)-16)/(2*pow(4,(TWSR&((1<<TWPS0)|(1<<TWPS1))))); //-->To get 100k bitrate
}

uint8_t TWI_start(unsigned char slave_address)
{
  uint8_t stat;
  TWCR=(1<<TWSTA)|(1<<TWEN)|(1<<TWINT);
  while(!(TWCR&(1<<TWINT)));
  //check the status
  stat=TWSR&0xF8;
  if(stat!=0x08){return 0;} // start condition fialed
  //write SLA+W to SDA
  TWDR = slave_address;
  //start transmision
  TWCR=(1<<TWEN)|(1<<TWINT);
  //wait until the ACK/Nack is received
  while(!(TWCR&(1<<TWINT)));
  //check the status
  stat=TWSR&0xF8;
  if(stat==0x18){return 1;} //ACK received, SLA+W/R successful
  if(stat==0x20){return 2;} //NACK recieved, SLA+W/R failed
  return 3;  //SLA+W/R failed
}

uint8_t TWI_repeated_start(unsigned char read_address)
{
  uint8_t status;
  TWCR=(1<<TWSTA)|(1<<TWEN)|(1<<TWINT);/* Enable TWI, generate start */
  while(!(TWCR&(1<<TWINT)));  /* Wait until TWI finish its current job */
  status=TWSR&0xF8;   /* Read TWI status register */
  if(status!=0x10)    /* Check for repeated start transmitted */
  return 0;     /* Return 0 for repeated start condition fail */
  TWDR=read_address;    /* Write SLA+R in TWI data register */
  TWCR=(1<<TWEN)|(1<<TWINT);  /* Enable TWI and clear interrupt flag */
  while(!(TWCR&(1<<TWINT)));  /* Wait until TWI finish its current job */
  status=TWSR&0xF8;   /* Read TWI status register */
  if(status==0x40)    /* Check for SLA+R transmitted &ack received */
  return 1;     /* Return 1 to indicate ack received */
  if(status==0x48)    /* Check for SLA+R transmitted &nack received */
  return 2;     /* Return 2 to indicate nack received */
  else
  return 3; 
}

uint8_t TWI_write(unsigned char data)
{
  uint8_t stat;
  TWDR = data;
  TWCR=(1<<TWEN)|(1<<TWINT);
  while(!(TWCR&(1<<TWINT)));
  stat=TWSR&0xF8;
  if(stat==0x28){return 0;} //ACK received
  if(stat==0x30){return 1;} //NACK received
  return 2; //Failed
}

unsigned char TWI_read_ack()
{
  TWCR=(1<<TWEN)|(1<<TWINT)|(1<<TWEA);
  while(!(TWCR&(1<<TWINT)));
  return TWDR;
}
unsigned char TWI_read_nack()
{
  TWCR=(1<<TWEN)|(1<<TWINT);
  while(!(TWCR&(1<<TWINT)));
  return TWDR;
}

void TWI_stop()
{
  TWCR=(1<<TWSTO)|(1<<TWINT)|(1<<TWEN);
  while(TWCR&(1<<TWSTO));
}
```

### The output I get

Most of the funtions return the status of the i2c bus using `TWSR` registor and using that the variable `uint8_t st` receive the return value ex.-0,1,2,etc. In my case all funtions return NACK and if they return NACK then the respective port pin will get **HIGH** else **LOW**.

1. `TWI_start()` returns NACK
2. `TWI_repeated_start()` returns NACK
3. `TWI_write()` returns NACK
4. `TWI_read_ack()` and `TWI_read_nack()` return `TWDR`
5. And in if for now `TWI_read_nack()` returns 0x97 then this will store in `unsigned char dat` and if it equals to 0x97 then `PB0` pin will get **HIGH**.

### Things I have tried

**On the breadboard-**

1. Tried changing the **24C04N**.(I have three of them)
2. Tried changing the pull-up resistor value to 1 kΩ and to internal pull-up too.
3. Tried changing the pin A0, A1, and A3 to VCC and A0,A1 to VCC and A2 to GND. But the thing I observed is when the pin A2 is connected to the VCC the IC-**24C04N** get hot-really really hot, this doesn't happen to A0 and A1.

**In the code-**

1. Tried changing the prescalar value from 1,4,16 and 64.
2. Tried changing the bitrate between 10kb to 100kb.
3. Tried changing the write address.
4. And slave address too, like 0x00 general call and other address too - with respect to A0, A1 and A2 pins.

Comment: You may have received fake chips, because the temperature rise for A2=VCC is not a normal behaviour.

Comment: Ohh, That could be the case. So the code looks fine?

Comment: I didn't went into code details, but it looks familiar. But before you spend much more time with the code, you may try this with another chip, bought elsewhere.

Comment: I think you have grounds and supplies mixed up. Your wiring is extremely hard to follow because all you have is a photo and there is no schematics or anything to compare with. Please check all wiring and pinouts to find any errors.

Comment: The connections to the EEPROM are as same as the first picture. The only thing is I swapped the GND and VCC on breadboard. But both the chips have correct supply to GND and VCC.

Comment: no, the connections are not the same

Comment: Can you please tell exactly which pins are not connected in the right way? Maybe you are pointing to the A0,A1 and A2 pins. Which are connected to the GND; Different from the first picture. I haven't connected the A2 pin to VCC because the 24c04 gets really hot.

Comment: Have you actually measured supply voltage value and polarity across the GND and VCC pins directly on the EEPROM chip? If you didn't, you can't claim you know anything about whether it's connected OK or not :)

Comment: Yes I did checked that before. Black lead of the multi-meter on pin4 and red lead of the multi-meter on pin8 and it gives 4.927v-dc , No negative sign unfortunately:)

Comment: The EEPROM I have is not working that is the problem.I tried this with another eeprom. Should I delete this question?